# Difference between 'data' and 'axes fraction' in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

What does `xycoords=('data','axes fraction')` mean? I have read

> https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html and it says that `'data'` uses the axes data coordinate system, what does this mean?

According to https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html `'data'` is the coordinate system of the data in the Axes; (0, 0) is bottom left of the axes, and (1, 1) is top right of the axes.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html says `'axes fraction'` is (0, 0) is lower left of axes and (1, 1) is upper right. So are `'data'` and `'axes fraction'` the same thing?

```
ax.annotate(percent, xy=(x, 0), xycoords=('data','axes fraction'), xytext=(0,-32), textcoords='offset points',va='top' ,ha='center')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to [matplotlib's transforms tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html), `'data'` is the coordinate system of the data in the Axes; (0, 0) is bottom left of the axes, and (1, 1) is top right of the axes.

From what I'm seeing, the `'data'` description does not include the second half about (0, 0) and (1, 1). If it's somewhere on the page that I've missed, that's a mistake and an issue/PR should be filed. That second half should only exist for the `'axes fraction'` description.

---

To clarify by example, here is the same point (2, 1) under different coordinate systems:

| `xy` | `xycoords` | `x` location | `y` location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (2, 1) | `'data'` | `x=2` | `y=1` |
| (2, 1) | `'axes fraction'` | 200% of the x-axis | 100% of the y-axis |
| (2, 1) | `('data', 'axes fraction')` | `x=2` | 100% of the y-axis |
| (2, 1) | `('axes fraction', 'data')` | 200% of the x-axis | `y=1` |

[image: demo of data and axes coords]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0, 10], [0, 5])

# at x=2, y=1
plt.annotate('data @ (2, 1)', xy=(2, 1), xycoords='data')

# at 200% x, 100% y
plt.annotate('frac @ (2, 1)', xy=(2, 1), xycoords='axes fraction')

# at x=2, 100% y
plt.annotate('(data, frac) @ (2, 1)', xy=(2, 1), xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'))

# at 200% x, y=1
plt.annotate('(frac, data) @ (2, 1)', xy=(2, 1), xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'))
```

Comment: Ohhh I see......so 200% of the x-axis is just the x-axis but twice as long.